# How would I filter on yesterday (not last 24 hrs) and show yesterdays date in my headers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating SQL reports to query results from NetBackup OpsCenter Database (MySQL?)
And am learning how to use SQL, so please forgive my ignorance.

The report I created below, shows the failures for the previous day (as opposed to previous 24 hours, which would be different each time its run).

```
SELECT (GETDATE()-1) AS 'Date', statusCode AS STATUS, COUNT(*) AS COUNT

FROM domain_JobArchive

WHERE DATEDIFF(day, UtcBigIntToNomTime(endTime), GETDATE()) =1
and masterServerId=59

GROUP BY statusCode;
```

And I wanted to change this, so it reports the Date being used as a header ... not its own column.

current output:

`Count of errors for yesterday (non-PCI)`

Date                       STATUS     COUNT
Apr 24, 2013 11:43:10 AM    288     1 
Apr 24, 2013 11:43:10 AM    0   6861 
Apr 24, 2013 11:43:10 AM    1   52 
Apr 24, 2013 11:43:10 AM    6   63 
Apr 24, 2013 11:43:10 AM    50      1 
Apr 24, 2013 11:43:10 AM    58      2 
Apr 24, 2013 11:43:10 AM    191     1 
Total 7 Rows , 1 Page(s)

desired output:

`Count of errors for Apr 24, 2013 (non-PCI)`

STATUS     COUNT
0   6861 
1   52 
6   63 
50      1 
58      2 
191     1 
288     1 
Total 7 Rows , 1 Page(s)

This way, each time you execute - it pulls up the same exact data.

And it would be even better, if it went from 7am yesterday to 7am today ... regardless of when its executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.  Subtract 7 hours from your date time, then compare it to yesterday's date.  You can just remove the date from you SELECT statement.  It's not needed.

```
SELECT statusCode AS STATUS, COUNT(*) AS COUNT

FROM domain_JobArchive

WHERE DATE(DATE_SUB(UtcBigIntToNomTime(endTime), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) = DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
and masterServerId=59

GROUP BY statusCode;
```

Comment: after testing it further ... would appear my original Query was working correctly, since it was checking for all records where the day differs by only (1).                                      DATEDIFF(day, UtcBigIntToNomTime(endTime), GETDATE()) =1

Comment: Good.  If you want to use the 7:00 AM - 7:00 AM range, you can subtract 7 hours from the date as I did above.